# Form doesn´t open in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm starting my experiment with VB.Net, I'm trying to open a new form and open the current one, my code looks like this:

```
   Private Sub bt_requisitar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bt_requisitar.Click
    Me.Close()
    IniciarSessao.Show()
End Sub
```

But when I click on the button the new form that was opened stays open for a few thousandths of a second and closes, can someone help me?

Comment: Assuming Me in this context is the application main form.  If so Me.Closing will end the application

Comment: Notice that right after I try to open a Form called "Start Session" but it opens for a few thousandths of a second and closes

Comment: Yeah I can see that, but like I said if Me.Close() is closing the main form of the application then the application is being closed.  That is why your Start Session form is only staying open for a few thousandths of a second.  Your entire application is closing

Comment: Project > Properties > Application tab > Shutdown mode = "When last form closes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me.close is will end the application , try this.

```
Me.Hide()
IniciarSessao.Show()
```